# Ipad dropdown does not show selected value when set by JQuery .val()

Tags: jquery, ipad

I'm using jQuery to clear and set the value on a dropdown. This works fine in IE, Chrome, FireFox and Safari. But on ipad the dropdown will show as blank. If you touch it, the correct value is there. But you cannot see it in the default state.

I thought maybe a stackoverflow user may have experienced this and know a quick answer.  Thanks!

```
setDropDownVal: function(element, value) {
        $(element).empty();
        var drp = $(element);
        drp.append($('<option></option>').val(value).html(value));
        drp.val(value);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

After trying multiple ways to force a redraw this fixed it.

```
setDropDownVal: function(element, value) {

        $(element).empty();
        var drp = $(element);
        drp.append($('<option selected="selected" value="' + value  + '">'
                      + value +
                     '</option>')); 
        //tried this to fix ipad does not work
        var n = document.createTextNode(' ');
        drp.appendChild(n);
        (function(){n.parentNode.removeChild(n)}).defer();

    }
```

http://ajaxian.com/archives/forcing-a-ui-redraw-from-javascript